# Can I hide built-in folders in Outlook 365?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, office365

We're using Office365 with the desktop Outlook client. There are several folders (RSS Subscriptions, Outbox, Junk Email) that I don't use. I don't want to delete them, but is there any way to hide them in the folder tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there are a couple of ways - none of which are straight forward.

You can use a tool like MFCMAPI
http://mfcmapi.codeplex.com/

MFCMAPI will let you set the hidden attribute on a folder.

You can use VBA (Press ALT+F11 to open the VBA editor) - select your folder and run the following:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub HideOutlookFolders()

Dim oOutlookFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim oPropertyAccessor As Outlook.propertyAccessor
Dim PropName, Value, FolderType As String


PropName = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10F4000B"
Value = True

Set oOutlookFolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
Set oPropertyAccessor = oFolder.propertyAccessor

oPropertyAccessor .SetProperty PropName, Value

Set oOutlookFolder = Nothing
Set oPropertyAccessor = Nothing
End Sub
```

Original Source:
http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/delete-outlooks-default-folders/